# Prove $\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt{2}}}+\sqrt[5]{6}$ is algebraic.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Why any expression of roots of rationals is algebraic?

My motivation to question is from the page $409$ of the book Michael Spivak  Calculus.

It is similar to say algebraic numbers are closed under taking roots.

I know that the set of algebraic numbers is field , but this means they are closed under addition and multiplication.

I think it is not efficient to always prove number is algebraic by finding polynomial with integer coefficients that has the number as root, which makes me think , there must be efficient way.

Comment: That this number is algebraic follows from the fact that the algebraic numbers form a field and that the $n$ th root of an algebraic number is again algebraic. To find a minimal polynomial is probably cumbersome , I suggest a numerical approach.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much , your comment answers my question very well.

The following question in MSE , explains the part of your comment about nth root of algebraic number is again algebraic number:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830994/are-the-n-textth-roots-of-an-algebraic-number-algebraic

Comment: I especially liked the following answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3831008/700480, as it explains in detail why it is true not only for radicals of algebraic numbers but for any solutions of a polynomial equation with algebraic numbers as coefficients. In other words, the set of algebraic numbers is closed for *solutions of polynomial equations* as well as for radicals (which is a special case of the former).